# Does a standard implementation of a Circular List exist for C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures, circular-list

I want to use a circular list.

Short of implementing my own ([like this person did](http://cppcorner.3x.ro/circularlist.html)) what are my options?

Specifically what I want to do is iterate over a list of objects.  When my iterator reaches the end of the list, it should automatically return to the beginning.  (Yes, I realize this could be dangerous.)

[See Vladimir's definition of a `circular_iterator`](http://cppcorner.3x.ro/circularlist.html): "A circular_iterator will never be equal with CircularList::end(), thus you can always dereference this iterator."

Answer (score 39, accepted):

There's no standard circular list.

However, there is a [circular buffer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html) in Boost, which might be helpful.

If you don't need anything fancy, you might consider just using a `vector` and accessing the elements with an index. You can just `mod` your index with the size of the vector to achieve much the same thing as a circular list.

Comment: Thanks Naaff!  Modding the index with the size of the vector is such a simple solution, I'm embarrassed I didn't think of it.

Comment: If you ensure that the size of your `vector` is a power of two, then instead of the expensive overhead of the modulus operation, use the bitwise `&` operator instead as it only costs one cycle. It works like this: `(n mod (2^k)) == (n & (2^k - 1))` e.g. `n % 256 == (n & (255))`

Comment: The compiler will replace mod with bit operations where appropriate for you anyway, no need to obfuscate code unless you really need the unoptimized debug performance

Comment: Unfortunately `-1 % n` almost never does what you want here, failing differently for signed and unsigned `n`. (Except for unsigned `n` that is a power of two.)

Ask me how I know

Answer (score 22):

If you want something looking like an iterator you can roll your own, looking something like

```
template <class baseIter>
class circularIterator {
    private:
        baseIter cur;
        baseIter begin;
        baseIter end;
    public:
        circularIterator(baseIter b, baseIter e, baseIter c=b)
            :cur(i), begin(b), end(e) {}
        baseIter & operator ++(void) {++cur; if(cur == end) {cur = begin;}}
};
```

(Other iterator operations left as exercise to reader).

Answer (score 6):

```
list<int>::iterator circularNext(list<int> &l, list<int>::iterator &it)
{
    return std::next(it) == l.end() ? l.begin() : std::next(it);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @captain-segfault and @mahmoud-khaled's iterator-focused answers, you can also use `std::list` as a circular list by altering what you do to retrieve elements from it.  Use [splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) to move one end of the list to the other end as you process it.

```
template <typename T>
T & circularFront(std::list<T> & l)
{
  l.splice(l.end(), l, l.begin());
  return l.back();
}
template <typename T>
T & circularBack(std::list<T> & l)
{
  l.splice(l.begin(), l, l.rbegin());
  return l.front();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this solition. Works fine for me.

```
std::list<int> List{ 1,2,3,4,5,6 };

    auto it = List.end();

    it--;

    it._Ptr->_Next = List.begin()._Ptr; // Next Node of the last elemen is now first elemen of the List
    List.begin()._Ptr->_Prev = it._Ptr; // Prev Node of the first element is now Last node

    for (int num : List)
    {
        std::cout << num << '\n';
    }
```

In this case we will loop indefinitely. Should work backward too.

## **Output**

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
2
3
4
5
6
1
.
.
```

Comment: Hi Doctor smail, the question here is not about making a linked list circular, Runcible is looking for a *list class* that is circular.