# Which is the best data-structure for iterating through arrangements of a string?

Tags: c++, stl, data-structures

Lets say, we have string "ABCAD", now we need to iterate through all possible arrangement of this string in both clockwise and counter-clockwise direction.

My ugly implementation looks like this:

```
string s = "ABCAD";
string t ="";
 for(int i = 0; i < sz(s); i++){
    t = s[i];
  for(int j = i+1; ; j++){
      if((j) == sz(s)){
         j = 0;
        }
       if(j == i){
          break;
        }
       t+= s[j];
     }
     cout<<t<<" ";
   }
reverse(all(s));
 for(int i = 0; i < sz(s); i++){
    t = s[i];
  for(int j = i+1; ; j++){
      if((j) == sz(s)){
         j = 0;
        }
       if(j == i){
          break;
        }
       t+= s[j];
     }
     cout<<t<<" ";
   }
```

**Output:**

**AHSAU
HSAUA
SAUAH
AUAHS
UAHSA
UASHA
ASHAU
SHAUA
HAUAS
AUASH**

I know that too naive,AFAIK a circular list would be a better choice, could somebody implement the same thing more efficiently using STL ?

Comment: If you want a circular list: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pseudocode, I'd go this route:

```
function rearrange (string s) {
  string t = s + s;
  for (int i = 0; i < length(s); ++i)
    print t.substring(i, length(s));
}

input = "ABCAD"

rearrange(input);
rearrange(reverse(input));
```

There's probably a way to rewrite rearrange() using functors, but my STL-fu is rusty.

Comment: Yeah that's lovely :) You know I just got it myself and then I saw your answer :)

Comment: You can do it in one call to `rearrange` like this : `function rearrange (string s) {
  string t = s + s;
  string q = reverse(s) + reverse(s);
  for (int i = 0; i < length(s); ++i){
    print t.substring(i, length(s));
    print q.substring(i, length(s));
   }
}`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is not  a data structure but an algorithm -  see [next_permutation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/next_permutation/)

Comment: Total number of permutation of "ABCAD" will be 5!/2! = 60,where as I need only 10.

Comment: @nthrgeek Do you mean unique permutations? In that case save each one in a std::set as it is generated.

Comment: It's just all rotation clockwise and counter-clockwise :)

Comment: @nthrgeek How can "direction" make a difference? If I have "AB" the only possible unique permutations "AB" and "BA".

Comment: Please enlighten me bu solving the problem using next permutation. :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is the [rotate](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/) algorithm. For the reverse ones, you'll need to do the reverse as you did in your own code.

Untested code to do what yours does:

```
std::string s = "ABCAD"

for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); ++i)
{
  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  std::rotate(s.begin(), s.begin() + 1, s.end());
}

reverse(s.begin(), s.end());

// same loop as above for reverse "arrangements"
```

Comment: Put the for loop in its own function and I'm sold.