# c++ loop data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator, linked-list, stdclass

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does a standard implementation of a Circular List exist for C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c)

Is there ready a template class in some c++ library that is some kind of a loop: A liked list where the last node references the first one.

Admittedly this wouldn't always be a practical class to use since there couldn't exist a end() iterator nor a well defined begin() iterator. But I could really have use for one and I was hoping that I wouldn't have to code it myself.

Edit:

Thank you both (Vivek Goel and madmik3) and for your answers, but unfortunately they have nothing to do with my question (I suggest http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list to you both). I also found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c), didn't find it yesterday. I apologise for posting the same question.

Comment: It's called a **circular linked list**.

Comment: @petter I am still curious why the two answers have nothing to do with what you need? They seem to be perfect answers?

Comment: They are not liked. Their iterators do not loop. There is a risk of writing over nodes and pointers may then not point to what you would expect them to point at. I know that you could make a circular linked list wrapper using circular buffer, but I don't see any advantage in doing so.

Answer (score 1):

What about Circular Buffer from boost 
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

Answer (score 0):

Boost has a circular buffer.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html

You can also see sample code here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_buffer