# Can I make a looped std::list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list, iterator, std, stdlist

I need a LinkedList with a loop in it, and want to manipulate pointers, etc. I was wondering if I could use std::list instead of implementing my own LinkedList class, and use its iterators almost the way I use pointers. But it seems that iterators don't let me do so. This is what I tried to do, which doesn't look right, I know. I'm new to std, please bear with me!

I expect the beginning of the loop to be at node 100.

```
int main() {
  std::list<int> l = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 100, 103, 104, 106};

  std::list<int>::iterator it1 = l.begin();
  while (*it1 != 100) it1 = std::next(it1);

  std::list<int>::iterator it2 = l.begin();
  while (*it2 != 106) it2 = std::next(it2);

  std::next(it2) = it1;  //(106)->next = 100

  std::cout << *(std::next(it2)); //it won't print 100, (obviously?)
}
```

I think I am completely wrong trying to treat iterators as pointer, but is there absolutely no way I can skip implementing my own LinkedList?

Comment: What is the looped list?

Comment: Are you trying to make a circular linked list?

Comment: @Yalda If I have understood correctly you can not do this with the standard list.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow like a circular list, except the "supposedly" last element's "next" some element in the middle. Like `106->next` will be `100`, rather than `1`, in my example list

Comment: @NathanOliver No, my list will start the circle after a number of elements

Comment: You could do this if you created your own `iterator`.

Comment: @Galik thanks, I guess the whole point of std classes is to not mess with pointers, list ending, etc, so it obviously doesn't let me use them in that way :)

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c