# Create circular linked list using std::list?

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl, iterator

So, I've been wondering if there is a way to create a ***circular linked list with std::list in c++***.
I can't seem to figure out a way to get the last element to point to the first.
Any ideas how someone could do that?

Comment: You can't force a `std::list` to act this way, but you can wrap it with something that will. (`boost::iterator_adapator` could be very useful.)

Comment: With `std::list` you don't get to control the links. So you can't.

Comment: you might find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947489/does-a-standard-implementation-of-a-circular-list-exist-for-c

Answer (score 2):

std::list interface doesn't support a circular list where first.prev is a pointer to last, and last.next is a pointer to first.

You can't decrement the iterator returned by std::list::begin(). More generally, you can't decrement any iterator returned by std:: ... ::begin().

Incrementing the iterator returned by std::list::back() results in an iterator == std::list::end() (the same is true in general for std:: ... :: back()).

---

If you're curious, Visual Studio template implements std::list internally using a dummy node as part of a circular doubly linked list. dummy.next points to first, dummy.prev points to last, and first.prev == last.next == pointer to dummy node, but this doesn't allow you to treat this as a conventional circular doubly linked list.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not.

`std::list` does not allow you to control the links yourself. The list controls the links for you. You cannot customize them.

Note that if you *could* customize the links in the list, the functions in the list would probably not work correctly. For example, if you iterated over a circular list, you'd never finish!

Comment: one can write a circular list backed up by a `std::list`, also the fact that a circular list has no `end` is not specific to implementing a circular list with `std::list`, its just what makes a circular list circular

Comment: @idclev463035818 If you used the same code designed for a non-circular list with a circular list, it might never finish iterating.